# Off RingtoneManager song android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have tried many solutions such as-

`RingtoneManager.stopPreviousRingtone();`

But it comes with an error of -
`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method stopPreviousRingtone() from the type RingtoneManager`

**MyAlarmService.java**

```
package com.example.getbettersoon;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    static Ringtone ringtone;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //RingtoneManager.stopPreviousRingtone();
        ringtone.stop();   // THIS DOES NOT STOP THE RINGTONE
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Uri alarm = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
         ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarm);
         ringtone.play();
    }


}
```

**Alarm.java**

```
package com.example.getbettersoon;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends Activity {

    String gethours;
    int myNum;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


            public void SetAlarm(View arg0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);          // test

                //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bthrs);
                //tv.setText(myNum);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            };


            public void OffAlarm(View arg0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                // Tell the user about what we did.
                Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            };

    }
```

When my button is pressed, the ring tone starts after 10 seconds but when I press the stop button the music doesn't stop. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Try to reduce the code to the parts that are relevant for your question, to encourage people to work through it and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are relying on your service being stopped to stop the ringtone playback. The line:

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

merely removes the service from being deployed in the future by the AlarmManager and **does not** stop an active service.

To stop a running service you need to use `Context.stopService()`

For example:

```
public void OffAlarm(View arg0){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    // Stops an existing running service

    stopService(myIntent);

    // Tell the user about what we did.
    Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

only then will the `onDestroy()` method be called by the android system and your ringtone stopped.